# Google Chrome Changing Graphic Color

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, background-color

Google Chrome always seems to be changing the color of an image that I'm trying to match to a background color. I tried saving it in Photoshop and GIMP and even adjusted the color settings in each but it doesn't help in Chrome. FF and IE work fine (for once).

The color of my image is #282828. After I saved it as a PNG, I reopened it in both GIMP and Photoshop and used the eyedropper tool to confirm that the color was still #282828. When it renders in Chrome it's darker. I have a div with a background color of #282828, and the image is right next to it. I took a screen shot and the div's background color was #282828 and the images background color was #1d1d1d. I tried this for several different colors and each has had the same result. I even tried making the source image the color Chrome was rendering it as but Chrome still changes it. So for example, since Chrome was changing #282828 to #1d1d1d, I made the source image #1d1d1d, and when I rendered it in Chrome it was not #1d1d1d, but some other darker color.

At this point, I'm looking for either a fix or a programmatic work-around. Because the image is transparent, has curves, and a drop-shadow, there's really no way for me to avoid replacing the it, or even parts of it, with html.

Update:
I also tried saving it as a jpg and gif. gif actually works but can't preserve the drop shadow. The image I'm using is attached. If I take a screenshot of this in Chrome, GIMP's eyedropper tool says it's #1d1d1d. If I open the original and do the same, it's #282828.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide link so we can see this actually happening?

Comment: Maybe it's an [optical illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grey_square_optical_illusion.PNG)

Comment: The last time I had this issue, it turned out to be something about how Photoshop handles the PNG format when saving, AFAIK.  This problem does not happen with JPG or GIF formats.  Since it's a PS issue, try using a different graphics editor to save the image.  Otherwise, perhaps you can save the image as a JPG with the proper background color in place of the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

[PNG uses gamma correction](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/) to try to ensure that the image looks kinda the same across all monitors, and this can cause color mismatches like the one you're seeing. It's a combination of image editor issues and browser issues: image editors are not forced to embed gamma data inside images, and browsers are free to ignore the gamma correction if it's there and free to enforce some at random when it's not there. In this case, I'd rather think that Firefox ignores it.

Use a transparent PNG if you don't want its background to interfere with your page's background.

[EDIT] For your specific case, you may be able to replicate the graphics you're looking for by styling elements, using `border-radius` and `box-shadow`, two widely-implemented CSS3 properties that reasonably decay on older browsers.